# Background image в ios app swift

Tags: ios, swift

Суть в следующем, нужно на view в xcode поставить картинку на background, что бы она вела себя как в сss -`background-size: cover;` контент должен скроллится вместе с картинкой, а так же наложить на нее полупрозрачное серое затенение как в css `rgba(47, 89, 107, 0.25);`

P.S. если реализация требует написания кода - то язык swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого необходимо создать `UIScrollView` и добавить в него следующие элементы:

1. `UIImageView` для отображения фонового изображения
2. `UIView` для затемнения изображения
3. `UILabel` для отображения нужного текста

[Репозиторий](https://github.com/Jauzee/ScrollViewWithBackgroundImage) для демонстрации

Comment: Да, все верно вы описали, если не сложно просьба выложить то же самое но сделанное через storyboard